# JavaFX Asteroids Game Clone: Having trouble bouncing asteroids off eachother

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to make an Asteroids game clone in JavaFX. So far, I have been able to draw the ship and asteroids onto the screen (where Rectangles represent them, for now). I have also implemented movement for the ship, and randomized movements for the asteroids.

I am having trouble implementing the code needed to bounce the asteroids off each other. The current method that does the collision checking (called `checkAsteroidCollisions`) is bugged in that all asteroids start stuttering in place. They don't move, but rather oscillate back and forth in place rapidly. Without the call to this method, all asteroids begin moving normally and as expected.

Instead, I want each asteroid to move freely and, when coming into contact with another asteroid, bounce off each other like in the actual Asteroids game.

MainApp.java

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashSet;

    import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.event.EventHandler;
    import javafx.scene.Group;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
    import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
    import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
    import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
    import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class MainApp extends Application {
        private static final int WIDTH = 700;
        private static final int HEIGHT = 900;

        private static final int NUM_OF_ASTEROIDS = 12;
        private static final Color ASTEROID_COLOR = Color.GRAY;

        private static final Color PLAYER_COLOR = Color.BLUE;

        private Player player;
        private ArrayList<Entity> asteroids;

        long lastNanoTime; // For AnimationTimer

        HashSet<String> inputs; // For inputs

       private static final int MAX_SPEED = 150;
       private static final int SPEED = 10;
       private static final int ASTEROID_SPEED = 150;

private StackPane background;

/*
 * Generates a random number between min and max, inclusive.
 */
private float genRandom(int min, int max) {
    return (float) Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

/*
 * Initializes the asteroids
 */
private void initAsteroids() {
    this.asteroids = new ArrayList<Entity>();
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_ASTEROIDS; i++) {
        Entity asteroid = new Entity(50, 50, ASTEROID_COLOR, EntityType.ASTEROID);
        float px = (float) genRandom(200, WIDTH - 50);
        float py = (float) genRandom(200, HEIGHT - 50);
        asteroid.setPos(px, py);

        // Keep recalculating position until there are no collisions
        while (asteroid.intersectsWith(this.asteroids)) {
            px = (float) genRandom(200, WIDTH - 50);
            py = (float) genRandom(200, HEIGHT - 50);
            asteroid.setPos(px, py);
        }

        // Randomly generate numbers to change velocity by
        float dx = this.genRandom(-ASTEROID_SPEED, ASTEROID_SPEED);
        float dy = this.genRandom(-ASTEROID_SPEED, ASTEROID_SPEED);
        asteroid.changeVelocity(dx, dy);

        this.asteroids.add(asteroid);
    }
}

/*
 * Initializes the player
 */
private void initPlayer() {
    this.player = new Player(30, 30, PLAYER_COLOR, EntityType.PLAYER);
    this.player.setPos(WIDTH / 2, 50);
}

/*
 * Checks collisions with screen boundaries
 */
private void checkOffScreenCollisions(Entity e) {
    if (e.getX() < -50)
        e.setX(WIDTH);
    if (e.getX() > WIDTH)
        e.setX(0);
    if (e.getY() < -50)
        e.setY(HEIGHT);
    if (e.getY() > HEIGHT)
        e.setY(0);
}

/*
 * Controls speed
 */
private void controlSpeed(Entity e) {
    if (e.getDx() < -MAX_SPEED)
        e.setDx(-MAX_SPEED);
    if (e.getDx() > MAX_SPEED)
        e.setDx(MAX_SPEED);
    if (e.getDy() < -MAX_SPEED)
        e.setDy(-MAX_SPEED);
    if (e.getDy() > MAX_SPEED)
        e.setDy(MAX_SPEED);
}

/*
 * Controls each asteroid's speed and collision off screen
 */
private void controlAsteroids(ArrayList<Entity> asteroids) {
    for (Entity asteroid : asteroids) {
        this.checkOffScreenCollisions(asteroid);
        this.controlSpeed(asteroid);
    }
}

/*
 * Checks an asteroid's collision with another asteroid
 */
private void checkAsteroidCollisions() {
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_ASTEROIDS; i++) {
        Entity asteroid = this.asteroids.get(i);
        if (asteroid.intersectsWith(this.asteroids)){
            float dx = (float) asteroid.getDx();
            float dy = (float) asteroid.getDy();
            asteroid.setDx(0);
            asteroid.setDy(0);
            asteroid.changeVelocity(-dx, -dy);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");

    this.initAsteroids();
    this.initPlayer();

    background = new StackPane();
    background.setStyle("-fx-background-color: pink");

    this.inputs = new HashSet<String>();

    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent e) {
            String code = e.getCode().toString();
            inputs.add(code);
        }

    });

    scene.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent e) {
            String code = e.getCode().toString();
            inputs.remove(code);
        }

    });

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

    background.getChildren().add(canvas);
    root.getChildren().add(background);

    lastNanoTime = System.nanoTime();

    new AnimationTimer() {
        @Override
        public void handle(long currentNanoTime) {
            float elapsedTime = (float) ((currentNanoTime - lastNanoTime) / 1000000000.0);
            lastNanoTime = currentNanoTime;

            /* PLAYER */
            // Game Logic
            if (inputs.contains("A"))
                player.changeVelocity(-SPEED, 0);
            if (inputs.contains("D"))
                player.changeVelocity(SPEED, 0);
            if (inputs.contains("W"))
                player.changeVelocity(0, -SPEED);
            if (inputs.contains("S"))
                player.changeVelocity(0, SPEED);
            // Collision with edge of map
            checkOffScreenCollisions(player);
            // Control speed
            controlSpeed(player);
            player.update(elapsedTime);

            /* ASTEROIDS */
            gc.setFill(ASTEROID_COLOR);

            for(int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_ASTEROIDS; i++) {
                checkAsteroidCollisions(i); // BUGGY CODE   
            }
            controlAsteroids(asteroids);

            gc.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

            for (Entity asteroid : asteroids) {
                asteroid.update(elapsedTime);
                asteroid.render(gc);
            }

            gc.setFill(PLAYER_COLOR);
            player.render(gc);
        }

    }.start();

    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

Entity.java:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
    import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
    import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

    public class Entity {
        private Color color;
        private double x, y, width, height, dx, dy;
        private EntityType entityType; // ID of this Entity

public Entity(float width, float height, Color color, EntityType type) {
    this.x = this.dx = 0;
    this.y = this.dy = 0;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.color = color;
    this.entityType = type;
}

/*
 * Getters and setters
 */
public Color getColor() {
    return color;
}

public void setColor(Color color) {
    this.color = color;
}

public double getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(float x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public double getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(float y) {
    this.y = y;
}

public double getDx() {
    return dx;
}

public void setDx(float dx) {
    this.dx = dx;
}

public double getDy() {
    return dy;
}

public void setDy(float dy) {
    this.dy = dy;
}

public EntityType getEntityType() {
    return entityType;
}

/*
 * Adds to dx and dy (velocity)
 */
public void changeVelocity(float dx, float dy) {
    this.dx += dx;
    this.dy += dy;
}

/*
 * Sets position
 */
public void setPos(float x, float y) {
    this.setX(x);
    this.setY(y);
}

/*
 * Gets new position of the Entity based on velocity and time
 */
public void update(float time) {
    this.x += this.dx * time;
    this.y += this.dy * time;
}

/*
 * Used for collisions
 */
public Rectangle2D getBoundary() {
    return new Rectangle2D(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
}

/*
 * Checks for intersections
 */
public boolean intersectsWith(Entity e) {
    return e.getBoundary().intersects(this.getBoundary());
}

/*
 * If any of the entities in the passed in ArrayList 
 * intersects with this, then return true;
 */
public boolean intersectsWith(ArrayList<Entity> entities) {
    for(Entity e : entities) {
        if(e.getBoundary().intersects(this.getBoundary()))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}


/*
 * Draws the shape
 */
public void render(GraphicsContext gc) {
    gc.fillRoundRect(x, y, width, height, 10, 10);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Entity [x=" + x + ", y=" + y + ", width=" + width + ", height=" + height + ", entityType=" + entityType
            + "]";
}

}
```

Comment: I've put an edit in removing that first paragraph from the question - there is a voting system on the website, where your question is scored. Generally a positive score means a good question, negative score is a bad question. If it's bad you may get comments added asking to you to give more information or something, but if it's good you're unlikely to be explicitly told!

Comment: Your check includes a check for whether each asteroid intersects itself, since you check every asteroid against every asteroid - clearly this is always true, so every asteroid will "bounce" on every frame.

Comment: There's some other bugs in there you will probably uncover when you fix that. When the asteroids collide, you just negate the velocity. This would be appropriate if they were bouncing off a wall angled at 45 degrees; but this won't look right for the actual collision of the asteroids. (If both are the same size, you want to bounce them off the line perpendicular to the line joining the centers of the asteroids; if not,  use the equations of conservation of momentum.) It's possible you will still get "oscillation" because you might not move them far enough to no longer be colliding next frame.

Comment: You might want to look at this example (which just animates balls bouncing off each other): https://gist.github.com/james-d/8327842

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to change the position of the two colliding asteroids slightly so their state is not on collision anymore.

What happens right now is that you change their movement after the collision but I guess that your algorithm notices that they are still touching, so it will try to change the movement again with the same result as before.

What you need to implement now is a change in the position of the two asteroids so your collision detection won´t act up again immediately after it´s first call.

I hope I could help you.

Comment: There are other issues with the OP's code; this may arise once those issues are fixed. The way I usually deal with this possibility is to define two things as colliding if they intersect *and* the distance between them is decreasing (which is reasonably easy here since the asteroids keep a reference to their velocity). This avoids the arbitrary movement hack (which is probably ok here, but not, say, in a physics simulation).